# Does rvalue reference parameter of built-in types make sense in terms of API design?

Tags: c++, c++11, api-design, move-semantics

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

class RAIIFile {
    public:
        RAIIFile(std::FILE *&&f):file{f} { }
        ~RAIIFile(){/*std::fclose and handle error*/}
    private:
        std::FILE *file;
};

int main(void) {
    std::FILE *etc = std::fopen("/etc/fstab", "r");
    // RAIIFile f{etc}; // ill-formed program: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘FILE*&&’ to lvalue of type ‘FILE*’
    RAIIFile f{std::move(etc)}; // ok
}
```

In the snippet above, `RAIIFile` ctor takes a rvalue reference to raw pointer as parameter. The merit is, this would force the client to provide a rvalue expression argument, which forbids he/she from using a raw pointer on stack, or reminds he/she that the ownership of `etc` raw pointer has been transferred.

I understand move semantics and its primary purpose. **My question is**, as a library coder, whether designing public API that takes rvalue reference parameter of raw type (e.g. raw pointer) is a good practice.

It seems that c++ spec has taken a negative opinion, good example being ctor of `std::unique_ptr` [taking pointer by-value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

Comment: you could take a `std::unique_ptr`, thats already sufficient to signal that `RAIIFile` takes over ownership

Comment: note that constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is explicit to prevent accidential ownership transfer

Comment: Why not use `std::ifstream` instead of `FILE*`?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Any scenario where taking `std::unique_ptr` is simply impossible?

Comment: sry I dont understand your comment. Your `RAIIFile` can be replaced by a `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter, but even if you want to keep `RAIIFile` you can use `std::unique_ptr`, no? `std::unique_ptr` is common and known and as you observed, it uses a different solution to prevent accidential transfer of ownership (one that is familiar to many)

Comment: Mixing pointers and (rvalue) references, kind of misses the point(er). You pass object instances by reference (temporaries by r-value reference). In C++ try to avoid passinng raw pointers of any kind (and yes there are exceptions, something to do with optional well known lifecycle by design).

Comment: Consider https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning. Before `std::make_unique` was a thing, raw owning pointers still appeared in code for a short moment of time to be passed to constructor of a `std::unique_ptr`, but nowadays there is no good reason anymore to have raw owning pointers like your `etc` out in the wild (even if ownership is to be transfered immediately). A function that takes a raw pointer should not participate in ownership. Your constructor violates this